# Overtime in MySQL timecard over two weeks

Tags: mysql, time, case

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the overtime on timecard bills that have been or need to be paid. The problem is that bills cover more than one weeks worth of hours and the query grabs more than one employee's history at a time. Any suggestions on how to do this, perhaps with a case statement of some kind?

For example, suppose in my list of employees one works 39 hours one week and 45 the next. The bill would show 84 hours worked, and would also need to show 5 hours of overtime (not four!). This needs to be done in the context of the below query, which handles multiple bills and multiple employees.

Note the query below shows how this would work if the billing period was only one week.

```
select
    username,
    CASE
        WHEN paidOn IS NULL THEN 'Unpaid'
        ELSE paidOn
    END as paid,
    round(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeOut, timeIn)))/3600,2) AS hours
    , CASE
       WHEN round(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeOut, timeIn)))/3600,2) > 40
           THEN round((sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeOut, timeIn)))/3600 - 40) * payrate + 40 * payrate,2)
       ELSE
           round(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeOut, timeIn)))/3600 * payrate, 2)
    END as pay
from
    timecard
LEFT JOIN
    employees
ON
    employees.userID = timecard.userID
WHERE
    paid != 'd'
GROUP BY
    paidOn, timecard.userID
ORDER BY
    paid DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it is that this works fine if the billing period is only 1 week, but not when you extend it to multiple weeks. Then I would simply use the query you have above as a subquery and then aggregate your weeks together. Here's a short example of what I mean:

```
SELECT
   EmployeeId,
   SUM(RegularPayHours) * RegularPayRate,
   SUM(OverTimeHours) * OverTimeRate
FROM
   (SELECT
      EmployeeId,
      DATEPART(week,TimeCardDate) AS [WorkWeek],
      CASE WHEN SUM(HoursWorked) > 40 THEN 40 ELSE SUM(HoursWorked) END AS [RegularPayHours],
      CASE WHEN SUM(HoursWorked) > 40 THEN SUM(HoursWorked) - 40 ELSE 0 END AS [OvertimeHours]
   FROM
      TimeCard
   WHERE
      TimeCardDate BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
   GROUP BY
      EmployeeId,
      DATEPART(week,TimeCardDate)
   ) a
WHERE
   WorkWeek IN (1,2)
GROUP BY
   EmployeeId
```

This will give you the first two work weeks combined as one result but with the overtime calculations done at the week level. You can essentially create any custom pay period that is X weeks long with this method.

You may need to custom define what a work-week is by setting the DATEFIRST value.